# StereoBM doesn't give proper output

Tags: java, opencv

I have seen many posts regarding this issue but this one is different. My code is working for one pair of an image but not working for another pair of an image.

Later, I want to convert video inputs from two cameras into a stereo output. I have tried that but that also have the same issue as the images (second pair of images) shown below.

**The below images gives expected output**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**The below images gives incorrect output**

[image]
[image]
[image]

How can I correct my code so that it will work for all images?

**Here is my code**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Mat left = Imgcodecs.imread("path", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat right = Imgcodecs.imread("path", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    Core.normalize(left, left, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_8U);
    Core.normalize(right, right, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_8U);

    StereoBM bm = StereoBM.create(16, 15);

    Mat disparity = new Mat();
    bm.compute(left, right, disparity);
    ImageProcessor.showResult(disparity);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void showResult(Mat img)
{
    Imgproc.resize(img, img, new Size(640, 480));
    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", img, matOfByte);
    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
    BufferedImage buffImage = null;
    try
    {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        buffImage = ImageIO.read(in);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(buffImage)));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, please specify what you mean by your code is "working" and "not working".  Also please specify a question.

Comment: @jwils "working" means "expected output". "not working" means "incorrect output"

Answer (score 0):

Look on both images in gray scale, after normalization - just as your algorithm sees it. At least, I would start from that.

It takes gray image and detects borders. Since all was normalized, probably borders from background are better seen then the one from your real object.

To fix that you can use different algorithm like [background subtraction](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html). Hope that helps.

Comment: But I want to find depth. Also, sample code would be nice.

Comment: Your algorithm detects object by their borders. That mean color change. Then two pictures are compared, and relocation of each object determines distance. Problem is with first step. Border is detected by color change, or better to say luminance change. So if two objects are grayish then it is hard to determine if they are two objects or singe lone. In your example whole flower is treated as background. So next steps are useless. Under provided link there are samples. In C++, but all names are the same.

Comment: What should I do to find the depth after background subtraction? Also, background subtraction won't work in my case because can be a scenario where there will be no foreground object Ex: Image of a Road

Comment: In [this site](http://www.cnblogs.com/cheermyang/archive/2016/01/09/5115354.html) they have used the same image to create a proper stereo output.

Comment: Sure - http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/disparity-mpas - contains same images + explanation + source code. And even more - not only C++, but Python as well.

Answer (score 0):

StereoBM computes correlation between two images. In second pair you have pattern visible on the wall - and that can cause problem (better correlation with another pattern element). As you can see, your plant remain black (furthest element, least distances between corresponding points).
In digital image correlation the more random distribution of intensities in image the better results are. There is much research done on special random patterns being added to object in order to increase randomness of intensity distribution.

https://orbi.ulg.ac.be/bitstream/2268/15779/2/Quality%20assessment%20of%20speckle%20patterns%20for%20digital%20image%20correlation%20(2006)%20(OCR).pdf

You can fix that problem by adding max distance constraints or modify you image with some distance-based function. As a origin of that function you could use point, which has two correlated points closest each other. Then you could perform second iteration.

Comment: But this was also in the stereo output created from video inputs from two cameras. There are no such patterns to affect correlation. For example, Man standing in a room.

Comment: Could you add result image of every step in your algorithm? Normalization could be an issue here.

Comment: "result image of every step" in the sense? Do you mean after normalize?